# Ringtone mode changed during incoming call in Android. Need for Text to speech app

Tags: android, text-to-speech, ringtone

During incoming call user can put the ringing of the phone in silent but pressing the volume up down or power on button in Android Phones. I am creating a speak caller name app where in my app will speak the name of the caller. I am not muting the current ringtone. Everything is working fine in  my app except when phone is ringing during incoming call and user put it on silent by pressing the volume or power button. I am unable to handle this trigger. I tried AudioManager and RingToneManager class but in vain.
My app has one activity (App settings), One BroadCast reciever class(for capturing incoming call) and one service(to trigger TTS engine).

Code :

```
    private void SpeakCallerName(String txtSpeak) {

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Ringtone ringtone = null;
            _status = "SpeakService speak Runnable phoneRinging: " + phoneRinging;

             Log.i("Test", _status);
             int i =0;


            try {
            while(phoneRinging) {
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                 _status = "SpeakService speak Runnable inside while loop count: "+i + "phoneRinging:" + phoneRinging;                   
                 Log.i("Test", _status);
                 int Mode = audioManager.getMode();

                 _status = "SpeakService speak Runnable inside while loop count: "+i + ":audioManager.getMode():" + Mode;                    
                 Log.i("Test", _status);

                 int ringerMode=audioManager.getRingerMode();
                 _status = "SpeakService speak Runnable inside while loop count: "+i + ":audioManager.getRingerMode():" + ringerMode;                    
                 Log.i("Test", _status);

                 int StreamVolume=audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
                 _status = "SpeakService speak Runnable inside while loop count: "+i + ":audioManager.getStreamVolume:" + StreamVolume;                  
                 Log.i("Test", _status);




            myTts.speak(_txtSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);


                Thread.sleep(5000);

                _status = "SpeakService speak Runnable count: "+i + " slept for 8 sec";

                 Log.i("Test", _status);
                 i+=1; 
            }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                _status = "SpeakService speak Runnable count: "+i + " EXCEPTION: " + e.getMessage();

                 Log.i("Test", _status);
            }



        }

     };

     Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
        mythread.start();
}
```

My log is like this:

SpeakService speak Runnable inside while loop count: 1phoneRinging:true
SpeakService speak Runnable inside while loop count: 1:audioManager.getMode():1
SpeakService speak Runnable inside while loop count: 1:audioManager.getRingerMode():2
SpeakService speak Runnable inside while loop count: 1:audioManager.getStreamVolume:7

When the user presses the volume or power button i still get the above values in the log.

Comment: Could you please clarify one thing: Your app is recording something the user says (a name of a contact, mainly) and you try to control the volume of the ring tone of an incoming call (especially incoming call, while user records) Why do you want to control that volume? From what I understand at the moment, there's no relationship between these two things.

Comment: I am not trying to record anything. My app will speak the name of the caller when the phone rings.My problem is when we receive any incoming all and if we press the volume or power button of the phone the ringtone goes into silent but incoming call continues. I want to handle this particular situation when during the ringing of the incoming call if user presses volume or power button the tingtone will become silent and i want my app not to speak the caller name in this situation. Hope this explains your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the volume of different channels like ringtone-volume or music/media-volume. The ringtone-volume would be obvious for your case and it should get silent as the ringtone itself gets silent. The music volume would have the volume of the last played music but would go silent anyway, with any incoming call. I have not seen a way to create and control your own channel.

If you use `SoundPool` I would go for this line to set it up:

```
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0);
```

Well, all that is how it should work in theory. I have experience in controling the volume for soundpools but not in conjunction with incomming calls. So, it's best you give it a try.

Comment: I have added my code to give more idea about my issue..I am using TexttoSpeech engine which is working fine. I want TTS to stop saying the caller name when during the ringing of the incominng call user presses volume or power button (which actually puts ringing on silence)